# Cmus not showing any songs after fresh install

Tags: arch-linux

I am trying to install and use cmus properly, but I am running into some trouble. All of the guides that I have found have me enter the following command to add music to cmus.

```
:add /home/username/path/to/music
```

when I do this and go into the browser tab, the folders that I added are there but none of the songs in those folders are visible. Note I have both mp3 files and m4a files.

Am I missing anything obvious? I couldn't find anything online regarding the issue that I am having. What can I do to get cmus to play the mp3 files that I have?

Answer (score 6):

Install missing optional dependency for mp3:

```
pacman -S --asdeps libmad
```

Figure out optional dependencies using:

- `pacman -Si cmus` or e.g.
- https://www.archlinux.org/packages/community/i686/cmus/

Answer (score 3):

- Close `cmus`,
- Go to `~/.config/cmus` and remove `lib.pl` file, if there is one.
- Then open `cmus`
- click "5" to go to browser
- locate root folder of your music (for me it is `~/Music`
- click "a"
- then click "1" to go to your library

you should see all your music being imported.

Comment: I ended up solving this problem by installing the dependancies for mp3 files, which I assumed were built in.

Comment: @bs7280 would you like to share what the dependencies you installed?

Comment: I'll try but I may have to wait a few days because I'm away from the computer I was using for this situation... I'll see what I can do once I get home from work

Comment: This did the trick for me, removed the lib.pl  and everything was running smooth again.

Answer (score -1):

for future reference

1. uninstall cmus
2. delete the cmus folder located at `.config/cmus`
3. then reinstall cmus

Comment: removing `.config/cmus` is likely enough

Comment: The OP was having this problem after a fresh install.   Why do you believe that another fresh install will behave differently?